# Javascript Change Image Src From an External .js File

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to change the image src of an image in my HTML file using a function I have stored in my scripts.js file. I have a script in here already that works so there is no issue connecting the file. Here is the working script I have.

**scripts.js**

```
function hideSelected(device) {
    if($('#addDevice').val() == 'tablet') {
            $('label[for=tabletsize], input#tabletsize').fadeIn(500);
            $('label[for=tabletcolor], input#tabletcolor').fadeIn(500);
    } else {
            $('label[for=tabletsize], input#tabletsize').fadeOut(500);
            $('label[for=tabletcolor], input#tabletcolor').fadeOut(500);
    }
}
```

**home.html**

```
<select name="device" id="addDevice" onchange="hideSelected();">
    <option value="tablet">Tablet</option>
    <option value="desktop">Desktop</option>
</select>

<img src="img/oldImage.png" id="myImage" />
```

For simplicity purposes, I have narrowed down the code. When I add the following code to the script (just for testing purposes, I am actually going to be adding it inside of another function), the image does not change.

```
$('#myImage').attr('src',"img/tooltip/category_feature.png");
```

How do I target and change the src of an image while hosting my function in another file? This script works PERFECT when I use it at the top of my HTML file, however, when added to another file, it doesn't. Although the fading part of the function works regardless of where I put it. Just not the image.

Thanks.

Comment: id for the image tag is `myImage` but you are using `addInstructionImage` while changing the source. Any specific reason??

Comment: The image file is relative to the script file. You might need to adjust the file location.

Comment: I was changing some variable names to make things a little more clear and forgot to change addInstructionImage. That is not the issue.

Jeff: The .js file is located 2 directories higher than the .html file. I tried ../../img as well as ../img and no luck. Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: The problem is you're using it at the top of the HTML file, which means when the code runs, `<img id="myImage">` doesn't exist yet. This is one of the most asked questions of all times. Wrap your code in `$(function () {` and `};` or move it to the end of `<body>`.

Comment: @jeff Not true, the script changes the DOM, regardless of its location. And the DOM doesn't move.

Comment: @ChrisG , is there anything else to be done other than just throwing that wrap around my code? What triggers the new function?

Comment: @TyJ It's a shortcut that causes jQuery to run the function after the document has finished loading. I forgot the `)` at the end though: `$(function () { ... });`

Comment: @ChrisG Still no luck. Everything works just fine except for the image for whatever reason. It's as simple as changing what is in the src. I don't understand why it won't work in an external file but has no problem running in the same file. I have even tried referencing the external scripts.js file in the footer.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your external script .js file at the bottom of all the scripts (jQuery etc) in your html bottom.

```js
function hideSelected(device) {
    if($('#addDevice').val() == 'tablet') {
            $('label[for=tabletsize], input#tabletsize').fadeIn(500);
            $('label[for=tabletcolor], input#tabletcolor').fadeIn(500);
    } else {
            $('label[for=tabletsize], input#tabletsize').fadeOut(500);
            $('label[for=tabletcolor], input#tabletcolor').fadeOut(500);
    }
}
$('#myImage').attr('src',"http://via.placeholder.com/300");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
<select name="device" id="addDevice" onchange="hideSelected();">
    <option value="tablet">Tablet</option>
    <option value="desktop">Desktop</option>
</select>

<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" id="myImage" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>


 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you load script file into html file. But what I could suggest is "IT's very important to make sure that JQuery is loaded and the end of html file after DOM loaded and your function call should also be place after JQuery script.

JQuery script could also be placed on header section of html file but it's not recommended.

Hope it help.

Comment: My script is referenced in the <head> as such

    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js">
    </script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/js/scripts.js">
    </script>

Even in the footer, the same issue occurs.

Comment: @TyJ For you question about the caching issue. When on development, I'd like to append random version number at the end of javascript/css script so they never get cached. E.g: https://yourdomain.com/include/script.js?v=[random_number]

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED. My original code was just fine. Apparently a refresh in the browser did the trick. For future issues, my current practice is to work in an incognito tab to avoid cookies and cache but ever so often, some changes I make won't take effect. I especially notice this with CSS. Any recommendations? Thanks.